# For loops and calling Arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have been tinkering with this for a little bit, slowly correcting it as I figure it out, but im fairly stumped now. It is to prompt the user for a name and to check it against the array values and return it. I got the motions down but it seems still not want to work correctly.
here are the specifics instructions.
[image: details of the set up]

```
onload = init;
var dwarfs = new Array();
dwarfs[0] = "Doc";
dwarfs[1]= "Grumpy";
dwarfs[2]= "Happy";
dwarfs[3]= "Sleepy";
dwarfs[4]= "Bashful";
dwarfs[5]= "Dopey";
dwarfs[6]= "Sneezy ";

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[4].onclick = 
    function(){
        dwarfCheck();
    }
   function dwarfCheck(){
        var name = window.prompt("Name a Dwarf from Snow White")
        var dwarfFound = false
for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
        if(name == dwarfs[i])
        dwarfFound = true

    }


window.alert(dwarfFound)
   }
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all – you are not even using your loop counter variable `i` to access the array elements, but you are checking all elements (well, apart from when the name is found in the first one already) seven times over with your loop.

Comment: And you are alerting the value of `dwarfFound` independently of whether the preceding `if` condition yielded true or not, which doesn’t make sense either.

Comment: I actually did not realize I left the first Else tag there. I had it for all of them but for what ever reason it would give me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dwarfs = new Array();
dwarfs[0] = "Doc";
dwarfs[1]= "Grumpy";
dwarfs[2]= "Happy";
dwarfs[3]= "Sleepy";
dwarfs[4]= "Bashful";
dwarfs[5]= "Dopey";
dwarfs[6]= "Sneezy ";
```

The above could be written as

```
var dwarfs = ["Doc", "Grumpy", "Happy", "Sleepy", "Bashful", "Dopey", "Sneezy"];
```

for shorter. Javascript allows you to define arrays this way.

Now, your function `dwarfCheck` is defined like it accepts a parameter `x` in

```
function dwarfCheck(x){ ....
```

but you are calling it without passing it any parameters here

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[4].onclick = 
function(){
    dwarfCheck(); //you are calling dwarfCheck without passing any parameter even though it expects a parameter x!
}
```

This would not be a problem, if only you were not actually using the expected parameter here

```
var dwarfFound = dwarfs[x]
```

so you have to sort that out.

And then your `for` loop is all weird, but it could be written correctly, like so

```
for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
    if(name == dwarfs[i]) {
        dwarfFound = true;
        window.alert(dwarfFound);
    }
}
```

and this way you do not need to write all these lines of repeated code, the loop will save you the typing.

Finally, get used to ending your statements with `;`. Javascript allows you to omit it in most cases, but it is good practice to use it.

Comment: Okay thanks I cleaned up the code some, though i kept the array in the long format, and got it all working and updated the post with the code as is. Also yeah it's a bad habit of my of not add the mark at the end.

Comment: @moliminous Neat. Now you could add some of the improvements suggested by MDrewT below, namely to break the `for` loop when a dwarf is found and only do the `alert` once, after the `for` loop is over and only if `dwarfFound === true`. Also, don't forget the curly brackets of your `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = window.prompt("Name a Dwarf from Snow White");
var dwarfFound = false; // You haven't found him yet
for (var i = 0; i < dwarfs.length; i++) {
  if (dwarfs[i] == name) {
    dwarfFound = true; // if dwarf number i is the one you're looking for, then this gets set to true
    break;
  }
}

if (dwarfFound) {
  window.alert("Found " + name + "!");
  dwarfFound = false;
}
```

Ok, a couple things. The main problem is in your dwarfCheck function. So I rewrote the internals a bit for you. You shouldn't need to pass in any variables because you're getting the name from the prompt in the function. You're also looping through the array so you're only dealing with one dwarf at a time (dwarf[i]). You just have to verify that that dwarf is not the one you're looking for. If not the loop will check the next one until it either finds it or has checked them all. I put in a break statement so that it won't keep looping after you've already found the dwarf (what would be the point?). Window alerts should generally have a meaningful message, not just TRUE or FALSE. and if you're going to run it several times you should set the value back to false when you're done. (It's just polite to clean up after yourself.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was going to make a really long-winded explanation on recursion, but honestly your answer does the job just fine. +1

Comment: Save recursion for later. You don't want to blow his mind too soon ;)